# How to see everyone who is online on slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We use the communication tool Slack. It shows online and away users that I have had direct message conversations with recently in my left sidebar. I would like to see everyone who is currently online, all the online users on our slack server, in a list. Having a list of users in a sidebar in a chat application usually means the online users, but not for slack, which confuses me greatly and often makes me falsely assume that a user is not online, when they are, I have just not sent a direct message to them recently.

Googling, searching the slack help and asking slackbot has not yet yielded any answers for me.

Is this feature possible to activate, or is there a plugin for it?

Answer (score 10):

Slack works a bit differently from what you might be used from other communication apps.

The list of users in your left sidebar does NOT represent the list of online users, but instead the list of users that you have recently had direct message communication with.

The online status of a user is reflected by the green circle next to his name. However, a user can still be reached even when the circle is grey (e.g. he might get a notification on his mobile when you text him). And if the user is on a mobile the grey circle just means that the Slack app is currently not active, but not that the user has logged out.

Also, a user will always remain in your list direct-message list and in the channel sidebar even when logged out as long he is a member of that channel and has a valid account.

The best approach to see everyone who is online is to go to a channel that everyone is in (e.g. your #general channel) and look for who has a green circle next to his name.

So in summary check for the color of the circle next to a user name to determine if he is online and remember remains reachable even if the circle is grey.

Comment: @Helena If this answer solved your question (which I believe it did) please consider marking it as solution. Ty.

Comment: Your answer doesn't solve the issue, it just explains the slack UI.

Comment: @daurnimator the question asked about how the slack UI works with respect to showing online users, which I answered. he also asked about a plugin, which is out of scope for SO

Comment: This question solves the issue in that it offers the best workaround - looking at the #general channel!

Answer (score 9):

There is not a good way to do this. The best that I have found is to do this by channel. Go to the channel, then click on the member list (upper left) and it will display all users in the channel with those that are online, sorted at the top.

Comment: As of January 2021, for the member list of a channel click on "(i)" in the top right corner or press Ctrl+Shift+I, then click on "Members"

Comment: Slack Version 4.31.156 does not sort channel members by online status.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [Slack API's users.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.list) method to list out all users' `presence` information. Note that the Slack API Docs mention that retrieving presence data for all users `reduces performance, especially with large teams.`

Comment: Interesting approach or idea, albeit still not quite the answer to the question about the slack UI.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that seems to work:

Go to any channel **->** select the `i` or `details` button **->** select members. Done! The list shows the members who are online first.

Comment: went to the general channel and did this - works

Answer (score 0):

[image: People & user groups]

View all people & user groups with their online/offline state.

[image: preferences]

Open preferences

[image: customize sidebar]

Always show `People & user groups` in the sidebar.